# Draw justified text with SWT

Tags: java, swt

Is there a way to draw justified text (just a single line) on a Canvas with SWT?

Right now I am using `gc.drawText` and it draws the text fine, but it can't draw it justified.

Comment: Please clarify what _justified_ means. If you want to align the text left/right/center, then use a `Label` and call `setAlignment()` with `SWT.LEFT`, or `SWT.RIGHT`, or `SWT.CENTER`.

Comment: `TextLayout` will do justification, but only if the text is too long for a single line.